# How do SQL Server users deploy for different licenses of the same release of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, license, enterprise-edition

Let's assume I want to deploy something like this to SQL Server,

```
ALTER TABLE foo
    ALTER COLUMN a varchar(11) NOT NULL
    WITH (ONLINE = ON);
```

This will work fine if your version of SQL Server is "Enterprise" but if you don't pay that much, you'll get this warning (as taken from *"Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU12) (KB4464082) - 14.0.3045.24 (X64)"*)

> Msg 1712 Level 16 State 1 Line 3
>
> Online index operations can only be performed in Enterprise edition of SQL Server.

What I would like to happen is that `WITH (ONLINE = ON);` is provided for users of Enterprise, but that if you're not on Enterprise, because the migration still must happen that it falls back to `ONLINE = OFF`?

There is no `ONLINE = IF_PAID_ENOUGH`,

```
| ONLINE = {   
      ON [ ( <low_priority_lock_wait> ) ]   
    | OFF }
```

Is there a supported mechanism to deploy to both crippled and non-crippled versions of SQL Server?

Comment: Is dynamic SQL an option? You could perform a lookup for the license version and construct the ONLINE = ON|OFF based off whether the license version returned is enterprise or not.

Comment: If that's all I can do, it's better than nothing I suppose. ;)

Comment: [How to create nonclustered index with online if available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407490/how-to-create-nonclustered-index-with-online-if-available/)